# Execute function in C++ after asynchronous 60 sec delay?

Tags: c++, stdasync

I've read this can be achieved using **std::this_thread::sleep_for** and **std::async**, but it's not working for me.

Here is the function to be called:

```
bool Log::refresh_data()
{   

    std::this_thread::sleep_for( std::chrono::minutes( 1 ) );

    std::vector<std::string> file_info = this->file.read_pending_if();

    for( auto line : file_info )
    {
        this->append( line );
    }

    return true;
}
```

Which is called from another function.  There are two examples of failed usage in the code below:

```
void MVC::refresh_data()
{
    // Error C3867  'Log::refresh_data': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member
    std::future<bool> retCode = std::async( this->model_log.refresh_data, 0 );        
    std::future<bool> retCode = std::async( this->model_log.refresh_data(), 0 );
}
```

Originally, **bool Log::refresh_data()** was **void Log::refresh_data()** but **std::async** didn't seem to like the void return...

Comment: What's the `0` for in your call to `std::async`?

Comment: Have you considered using a callback timer?
See this answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12904098/c-implementing-timed-callback-function

Comment: @Holt I thought the issue was somehow related to **std::async**'s args, so added the 0 in an attempt to make it work...as it liked **void** even less.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot pass a non-static method like this in C++, you can do:

```
auto retCode = std::async(&Log::refresh_data, model_log);
// Or with a lambda:
auto retCode = std::async([this]() { 
    return model_log.refresh_data(); 
});
```

These codes work with a `void` return type (you simply need to remove the `return` statement in the lambda).

Answer (score 1):

Because `refresh_data` is a method of `Log` you need to use `std::bind` with `model_log`, or use a lambda:

```
std::future<bool> retCode = std::async( [this] {return model_log.refresh_data(); });
```