# C++ call a function every x seconds

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am trying to run run() function every 5 seconds without stopping while() loop (parallelly). How can I do that ? Thanks in advance

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <thread>
    #include <chrono>

    using namespace std;

    void run() 
    {
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(5000));

        cout << "good morning" << endl;
    }


    int main()
    {
        thread t1(run);
        t1.detach();

        while(1)
        {
            cout << "hello" << endl;

            this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(500));
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Can you just use a `while` loop inside of `run()`?

Comment: Please take a couple of steps back, eat some good dinner, and go to sleep. In the morning, after a healthy breakfast, the solution (already mentioned above) should hopefully be pretty obvious.

Comment: this is a small simulation of a bigger code so assume there are lines of codes in while loop and they should not be stopped / waited.

Comment: :) sorry I m new on threads @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: Also there is no reason to use `detach` here (there rarely is a good reason for doing so)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [c++ Implementing Timed Callback function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12904098/c-implementing-timed-callback-function)

Comment: currently all answers assume that the runtime of ``run()`` is negligible. If ``run()`` takes a small but not negligible time, you might want to look into ``sleep_until``. If ``run()`` takes more than 5 seconds, then you can not longer combine ``run()`` with the sleep, but would need to start a new thread (or task if you have a threadpool) every 5 seconds.

Comment: @generic_opto_guy if run() takes more than 5 seconds and you spawn new thread for run() every 5 seconds eventually you will exceed system limits.

Comment: @idris would this even happen when I join all finished threads befor I spawn a new thread?

Comment: @generic_opto_guy it will not happen. But if you wait for spawn thread that mean you call run() function more than per 5 sec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call your run function in seperate thread function like below. Is this ok for you?

```
void ThreadFunction()
{
    while(true) {
        run();
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(5000));
    }
}

void run() 
{
    cout << "good morning" << endl;
}


int main()
{
    thread t1(ThreadFunction);
    t1.detach();

    while(1)
    {
        cout << "hello" << endl;

        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(500));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And does this really call `run` every _5_ seconds? ;)

Comment: eyvallah hocam :)

Comment: @churill yes it will. What is your doubt?

Comment: @idris `run()` will sleep 5 seconds and at the end of the `while` it will sleep 5 seconds again. Makes 10 if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @churill you right. What is happenning in run function can varry. I think it is a just stub function.

Comment: @idris Your function does not wait 5 seconds but 10. Morevover, you don't need to nest a function inside another one. Only one run function is enough, there was only a missing `while` loop as the first question's comments mentioned.

Comment: Another thing, `std::cout` is not thread-safe if I'm not mistaken. So having two threads accessing `std::cout` concurrently without synchronization mechanism (mutex, ...) is a data race.

Comment: @Fareanor you are right but the question is not about what is happening in run function. I just copy the code.

Comment: @idris Yes but StackOverflow is not meant to provide wrong answers. You should at least give advises, let OP know what is wrong in his code and propose a better way to achieve his/her goal. Completeness is a key to a good answer. Copying something wrong is... wrong.

Comment: @churill; @Fareanor (and therefore @Idris) your analysis is not correct. Wait times do not add up because the two 5 second waits **this_thread :: sleep_for (chrono :: milliseconds (500));** run on two different threads :
the first sleep runs on the main thread (relating to the main function), the second on the t1 thread. knowing that the two threads **main function thread** and **t1** live their lives separately ... until the end of the "main thread" program.

Comment: We cannot add up (in the sense +) the execution time (5s + 5s = 10s) of two entities (threads, process) which execute in parallel especially if they do not have direct constraints synchronization between them.

Comment: @Landstalker You are wrong, the answer has been edited after our comments. If you  have taken a look at the edits, you would have seen that in the original version of the answer, there was 2 `sleep_for(5000)` in the thread (one in run and another one in the `ThreadFunction`), not only one, hence the 10s.

Comment: @Fareanor Ok, i understend. That why I prefered indicated precisely which sleep is concerned: the sleep of the **main_thread** and the sleep of **ThreadFunction**

Comment: @Landstalker We are aware of it but we never talked about the main thread sleep. Before the edit, there was 2 sleeps in the same thread, that's all. Next time, be much careful and look at the edit/answer's improvements before claiming that other people's "analyses are not correct" ;)

Comment: @Fareanor Thanks ;)

Comment: @Landstalker No problem, without knowing the whole story, I can easily understand that the comments may appear quite surprising :)

Answer (score 4):

In your `main` function, it is important to understand what each thread is doing.

1. The main thread creates a `std::thread` called `t1`
2. The main thread continues and detaches the thread
3. The main thread executes your `while` loop in which it:

   - prints hello
   - sleeps for 0.5 seconds
4. The main thread returns 0, your program is finished.

Any time from point 1, thread `t1` sleeps for 5 seconds and then prints good morning. This happens only once! Also, as pointed out by @Fareanor, `std::cout` is not thread-safe, so accessing it with the main thread and thread `t1` may result in a data race.

When the main thread reaches point 4 (it actually never does because your `while` loop is infinite), your thread `t1` might have finished it's task or not. Imagine the potential problems that could occur. In [most of the cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22803600/when-should-i-use-stdthreaddetach), you'll want to use `std::thread::join()`.

To solve your problem, there are several alternatives. In the following, we will assume that the execution of the function `run` without the `std::this_thread::sleep_for` is insignificant compared to 5 seconds, as per the comment of @Landstalker. The execution time of `run` will then be 5 seconds plus some insignificant time.

As suggested in the comments, instead of executing the function `run` every 5 seconds, you could simply execute the body of `run` every 5 seconds by placing a `while` loop inside of that function:

```
void run() 
{
    while (true)
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(5000));
        std::cout << "good morning" << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::thread t(run);
    t.join();
    return 0;
}
```

If, for some reason, you really need to execute the `run` function every 5 seconds as stated in your question, you could launch a wrapper function or lambda which contains the `while` loop:

```
void run() 
{
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(5000));
    std::cout << "good morning" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    auto exec_run = [](){ while (true) run(); };
    std::thread t(exec_run);
    t.join();
    return 0;
}
```

As a side note, it's better to [avoid `using namespace std`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: Good answer, this should be the accepted one. But you could improve something. In the `main()` OP has written an infinite `while` loop. So your step 4 never happens (_"When the main thread reaches point 4"_).

Comment: What will happen if the processing time associated with the thread greatly exceeds 5 seconds? suppose 5 minutes!
The function will not be recalled at minute 1, nor at minute 2 ... If this is the desired bihaviour "ok". Otherwise, if you want that the function must be called every 5 seconds regardless of its processing time, this model is not suitable.

Comment: @Landstalker you are right. However, I think this is not the issue of the asker. The question would have been asked differently in my opinion.

Comment: @mfnx Ok, it was just to make sure we met her need.

Comment: This is actually what @generic_opto_guy has already commented on the question. But since the OP did not say anything about what should the `run()` function do, except a single `std::cout`, these considerations are not a concern here (but I agree it deserved to me mentioned).

Comment: @Landstalker I added a few lines to make this clear.

Comment: @mfnx I see. I find it more precise now with your modifications. now there is more ambiguity