# I want a function which can start a timer in C language?

Tags: c, timer, signals, clock, time.h

In C language, I want a function which starts a timer (in background) and after a certain time elapses, some interrupt will get called? In `signal()` is there any function?

Comment: Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12904098/c-implementing-timed-callback-function

Comment: You want [`alarm()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/alarm).

Comment: How many do you want, and on which platform(s)?  The options on current versions of POSIX vary from [`alarm()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/alarm.html) (which has a granularity of integral seconds) to [`getitimer()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getitimer.html)
and `setitimer()` (with a nominal granularity of microseconds) to
[`timer_create()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/timer_create.html) and its related functions (which has a nominal granularity of nanoseconds).

Comment: there is a signal, SIGALRM...